# While loop with if statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, while-loop

I am getting a syntax error with this due to the final while loop. I have tried switching it around but cant find the issue here - is it purely that MySQL doesn't support if statements within while loops?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE bLAHbLAHbLAH(p_fromdate datetime, p_todate datetime)
BEGIN

Declare startday datetime;
declare numberofdays int;
declare Counter int;

Set startday = p_fromdate;
Set numberofdays = (select datediff("2012-05-01","2012-11-01"));
Set Counter = 0;

WHILE startday<p_todate DO
    if (select date_format(startday, '%W')) in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday') THEN
        SET Counter = Counter+1;
        SET startday = date_add(startday, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    else
        SET startday = date_add(startday, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;

select Counter; 

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Believe it or not it did. Apologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot an

```
end if;
```

before the `end while`

```
WHILE startday<p_todate DO
    if (select date_format(startday, '%W')) in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday') THEN
        SET Counter = Counter+1;
        SET startday = date_add(startday, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    else
        SET startday = date_add(startday, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    end if;                                                   /*add this line*/
END WHILE;
```

Comment: You are a star, thank you so much. I didn't even realise you had to explicitly end an if statement in MySQL! Doh!!0